# Converting resolution to meter using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, resolution

I have data in the following format:

```
Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                      |
 |            N:  46:08:44N    S: 45:54:50.666667N   Res: 0:00:00.333333      |
 |            E: 96:30:27.333333W    W: 96:50:23.666667W   Res: 0:00:00.33333 |
 |   Range of data:    min = 291.4953  max = 338.9827
```

I need the resolution like as follows:
 Projection: Latitude-Longitude                                      |

```
 |            N:        50N    S:        45N   Res:     5                     |
 |            E:        95W    W:       100W   Res:     5
```

How can I convert Res: 0:00:00.333333 to meters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use linear units with the projection your data is using.  The feature class you have is using a Geographic Coordinate System, which only use angular units like degrees and radians.  You have to Project this feature class to a Projected Coordinate System, like State Plane coordinates, to be able to use linear units like meters.  The Project tool is what you would use to convert to a different coordinate system if you have ArcGIS desktop.